# My application (sever/client) is blocked after using Readline

Tags: c#, java, sockets, bufferedreader

Im trying to make a tcp connection between server and client . server is programmed on c# and cliend on java... server is working fine... my problem is in this code:

```
try {
  InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
  connection = new Socket(address, port);        
  BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
  loginInfo = inFromServer.readLine();
  System.out.println("username/pass are  received");
  System.out.println(loginInfo);
  connection.close();
} catch (IOException f) {
  System.out.println("IOException: " + f);
} catch (Exception g) {
  System.out.println("Exception: " + g);
}
```

The application is blocked and I can't close it any more... until i finish debug from java .
I guess the problem is in loginInfo because im not getting username/pass are received in output .. so any help?

this is the thread that send message from c# :

```
Thread listener_service = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
{
  listener.Start();
  while (true)
  {
    s = listener.AcceptSocket();
    Console.WriteLine("Connected to !" + s.RemoteEndPoint);
    ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
    s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server. \n"));
    Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");
    continue;
  }
});
```

Comment: Does you C# code send a string with a carriage return/newline at the end?

Comment: Why don't you write the `inFromServer.readLine()` within a `while` loop? How will you know if there is no more data to be read from the server?

Comment: ive just added the thread that send a message from server in c# .. ive been working 30 h on this problem and i didnt resolved yet .. i searched all the internet and didnt get a answer .. so i appriciate any help  .. im new with network connection

Comment: Put a `flush` call in your C# code after `s.Send`.

Comment: @GregKopff, Yes flushigng stream is most important . well spotted.

Comment: I don't know the C# libraries, sorry. (Your problem just matches the symptoms of not flushing a buffer, so that's my guess).

Comment: There is no StreamWriter in C# to use flush ... how should i use it ???

Comment: @jolyTimePopCorn Try to read an array of bytes `byte[]` instead of using `readLine()` and see what that does.

Comment: Any time you have difficulty with TCP client/server code where you wrote both, one of the first things you should do is test both ends against a small and portable open source program called netcat.  This should let you manually interact with each end (assuming you build it with the listening support option) and figure out which of your programs is behaving differently than you intended.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ive tried that .. still have the same problem ..

Answer (score 2):

calling `readLine()` is blocking call, means your code execution will be blocked until and unless you receive any line from server communication.

use `System.Environment.NewLine` instead of `\n` to terminate your line in `C#` code.

Comment: thats wrong ... No flush in c# for socket .. and im sure the problem is in java .. !

Comment: Not flush, but make sure you send an appropriate line ending character.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thats ture .. i put "/n" in the end but also not working .. !

Comment: Finalyyyy a genuis HEREEEE ! THX A LOT @Alpesh Gediya :D

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels haha yes ur right .. i should have wait !

Comment: @jolyTimePopCorn, hope it should have worked. so issue was in c#, right?